# Cannot understand how to group autocommands in this case

Tags: neovim, autocmd

I downloaded a program called calcurse and it allows me to make notes by making temporary files in `/tmp` folder. The  note files are named as `calcurse-note.[some random alphanumeric characters after dot]`. I wanted to use vimwiki syntax for those notes (vimwiki is a plugin for making wikis and has a syntax like markdown). Hence, I added an autocommand like this:

```
augroup vimwiki
     autocmd!
     autocmd BufNewfile,BufRead /tmp/calcurse-note* set filetype=vimwiki
     autocmd FileType vimwiki setlocal wrap
augroup END
```

The autocommand did not work. I made a separate augroup and it worked!

```
augroup calcurse
     autocmd!
     autocmd BufNewfile,BufRead /tmp/calcurse-note* set filetype=vimwiki
augroup END
augroup vimwiki
     autocmd!
     autocmd FileType vimwiki setlocal wrap
augroup END
```

I don't understand how is this working.

Separate from the above problem, another problem is that wrap is not working in vimwiki files with the above autocommand.

Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: Which parts are "working" and which not? Can you be more specific about what working means? Do you perhaps mean that, in the second code block, the vimwiki filetype/syntax are applied, but wrap is not? Please [edit] to clarify

Comment: OP, it looks like your edits came in anonymously. If you want to edit your original question, it's generally going to be best if you're signed in. It's your choice to participate, though.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry. I wasn't aware. Is my problem understandable now? :')

Comment: yes! Thank you. Unfortunately I don’t quite know what’s wrong, but perhaps someone else will be able to help

Comment: Oh... Okay! Thankyou. :)